# Login page doesn't work in browser but the method works with Postman

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, postman

I have a problem in my angular project with the login component as it won't load the login page but instead it will show this:[HTTP ERROR 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beAAe.png)

When I try to log in using Postman, it works perfectly so I don't understand why does it have this behaviour since I don't get any error in the console or browser[Postman status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT5OR.png).This is my login.component.ts:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ToastrManager} from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
loginForm: FormGroup;
loading = false;
submitted = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: LoginService,
    public toast: ToastrManager, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
email: ['', Validators.required],
password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
get loginFormControl() {return this.loginForm.controls; }
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
  return;
  }
  this.loading = true;
  this.loginService.login(this.loginFormControl.email.value, this.loginFormControl.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.toast.successToastr('Login succesfully');
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        },
        () => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.toast.errorToastr('Something went wrong');
          this.loginForm.reset();
          this.loginForm.setErrors({
            invalidLogin: true
          });
        });

 }
}
```

My login.service.ts:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Register} from '../Models/register';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
   httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer',
    })
};
  userData = new BehaviorSubject<Register>(new Register());
ApiUrl = 'https://localhost:5001';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router) {
    }
    login(email, password) {
      return this.http.post<any>(this.ApiUrl + '/login/login', { email, password}, this.httpOptions
     )
      .pipe(map(response => {
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', response.token);
        this.setUserDetails();
        return response;
      }));
    }
    GetById(id) {
      return this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + '/register/' + id , this.httpOptions);
    }
    doLogout() {
      const removeToken = localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
      if (removeToken == null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    }

    // User profile
    setUserDetails() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
        const userDetails = new Register();
        const decodeUserDetails = JSON.parse(window.atob(localStorage.getItem('authToken').split('.')[1]));
        userDetails.email = decodeUserDetails.sub;
        userDetails.name = decodeUserDetails.name;
        userDetails.isLoggedIn = true;
        userDetails.role = decodeUserDetails.role;
        this.userData.next(userDetails);
      }
    }

    handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
      let msg = '';
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // client-side error
        msg = error.error.message;
      } else {
        // server-side error
        msg = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
      }
      return throwError(msg);
    }
}
```

The login.component.html:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">    
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.errors?.invalidLogin" class="alert alert-danger mt-3 mb-0">    
      Email or Password is incorrect.    
    </div>    
    <div class="card">  
      <div class="card-body">    
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">    
          <div class="form-group">    
            <label for="email">Email</label>    
            <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" autofocus    
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && loginFormControl.email.errors }" />    
            <div *ngIf="submitted && loginFormControl.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">    
              <div *ngIf="loginFormControl.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>    
            </div>    
          </div>    
          <div class="form-group">    
            <label for="password">Password</label>    
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control"   
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && loginFormControl.password.errors }" />    
            <div *ngIf="submitted && loginFormControl.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">    
              <div *ngIf="loginFormControl.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>    
            </div>    
          </div>    
          <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">    
            <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>    
            Login    
          </button>    
        </form>    
      </div>    
    </div>    
  </div>
```

The LoginController.cs:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using AnotherAP.Helpers;
using AnotherAP.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace AnotherAP.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public LoginController(IConfiguration config,DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _config = config;
        }
      

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Register model)
        {
            IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
            Register user = AuthenticateUser(model.Email,model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var tokenString = GenerateJWT(user);
                response = Ok(new
                {
                    token = tokenString,
                    userDetails = user,
                });
            }
            return response;
        }

       string GenerateJWT(Register user)
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:SecretKey"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                new Claim("Name", user.Name.ToString()),
                new Claim("role",user.Role),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: credentials
            );
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }

      public  Register AuthenticateUser(string email,string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                return null;

            var user = _context.register.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email && x.Password==password);
           
            // check if username exists
            if (user == null)
                return null;
            return user;

        }
       
    }
}
```

This behaviour started happening after I modified the code in the controller for AutheticateUser() by using the data context instead of list declaration. Before that it would not recognise the credentials but the page was properly displayed, instead it would not work with Postman.Now it returns 200 Ok with Postman, but the page will not load.Did anyone encounter a similar problem and might know the cause?Any help would be appreciated!Best regards!

UPDATE:
This is the error I am geetting from the browser console:
[Browser console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp9dC.png)

Comment: what does your browser console show, may it be a cors problem? And is this route correct: '/login/login' ??

Comment: Thank you for your response.The browser console does not show anything as otherwise I would have checked the error.The CORS work perfectly as I declare the origin which is my localhost since I read that with authentication you must specify the origin you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you have a wrong route in your login.service:

```
  login(email, password) {
  return this.http.post<any>(this.ApiUrl + '/login/login', { email, password}, this.httpOptions
 )
```

Isn't it '/login' instead of '/login/login'?

Comment: My route inside the method is correct as login is the name of my controller and the other is the name of the action.You can also see it inside the LoginController.cs at Route[("login")].If you look over at the screenshot for Postman,you will see that this route is working.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the postman screen... But does the request looks right in the browser inspector? Did you double check username and password go out correct?

Comment: I can see that you had a point in what you were saying.My route in app.module.ts had path :'login' and returned a 401 unauthorised which I checked afterwards in Postman and indeed it was right,I changed it to {path: 'auth', component: LoginComponent} and now it displays the page but the login will not work.

Comment: now it shows 401 Unauthorized but with postman it works.I will update the question.

Comment: But what did you check that angular sent the right credentials in browser inspector? Maybe it is just an error with form that the values are empty or something like this...

Comment: My bad, now it works perfectly!Thank you for your help in figuring out the problem!I will mark your answer as correct.Best regards!